# Chrome extension to randomly revisit old bookmarks

Tags: chrome, bookmark

I have a *lot* of bookmarks for sites I want to revisit at some point.  These aren't necessarily blogs or other forms of periodic content, otherwise I'd just add them to my RSS reader.  These are things like languages or tools I want to learn, or maybe a game I want to play at some point.

**Is there a Chrome extension that will randomly select one of my bookmarks each day and present it to me, or do something similar in spirit?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Play Bookmark Random**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-bookmark-random/mdbefmimdllmigljlncggjdcjdpmcgna) does the trick.

Not very polished, but it suits my needs.